# Get all order made with detail from ubereat-API

Tags: uber-api

How to Get all order with details from an account using the ubereat-api ?
I think my searching skill on the documentation are bad.
I find a way to get all my data in CSV by asking here: [https://help.uber.com/riders/...](https://help.uber.com/riders/article/demander-une-copie-de-vos-donn%C3%A9es-personnelles?nodeId=2c86900d-8408-4bac-b92a-956d793acd11)

But i would love to know what the way from the API. Someone ?

Comment: I don't believe there is an API for normal users. I found the API for Uber Eats Partners, but there's little chance there is one for users.

Comment: Did you mange to get access to the data you requested?

Comment: Not yet, i manage to retrieve all my usier-data, i'm looking to use directly the data from the CSV.